# inputs and loops 

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to do as the picture shows here:
[image]

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IcsProject
{

 public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);
    int menuNum,ID,semNum,semCode,semCourses;

do{
        System.out.println("Please Enter your Choice from the menu:");
        System.out.println("1. Enter Student Sanscript");
        System.out.println("2. Display Transcript Summary");
        System.out.println("3. Read Student Franscript from a File");
        System.out.println("4. Write Transcript Summary to a File");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");

        menuNum = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (menuNum == 2 || menuNum == 3 || menuNum == 4)
            System.out.println("Not working");


    } while (menuNum > 1 && menuNum < 5);

//// Option 1: Enter student transcript


        if (menuNum ==  1)
            System.out.println("Please enter your student's FIRST and LAST name:");
            String stuName = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the ID number for " + stuName);
            ID = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of semesters");
            semNum = keyboard.nextInt();
            for(int i=1 ; i < semNum ; i++)
            {System.out.println("Please enter semester code for semester n# " + semNum);
            semCode = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the number of courses taken in " + semCode );
            semCourses = keyboard.nextInt();}
            System.out.println("Enter course code, credit hours, and letter grade ")

 ///I stopped here 
}
```

- Do I have to use array starting from the semester code? show me an example please.
- After entering all the values The program should show the Menu again so I can choose from it. How to do that?
- I'm having a problem at the first question "entering the student first and last name" 
  The program just skip it and move to next question. Is there a mistake with my `keyboard.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2):

I would use a list of objects which have all the fields you want to record.

For examples, just use google.

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+list+examples 27.9 million result

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+object+examples 18 million results.

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+array+examples 15 million results.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding issue #2 - put the menu in a separate method. use a loop that it's condition is the menu or something similar to process according to the result from menu (this is abstract, I think you can figure it out from here):

```
while(doAnotherLoop)
{
    switch(showMenu())
    {
    case 1:
     ...
    case 2:
     ...
    case 5: // Exit
        doAnotherLoop = false;
    }
}
```

Regarding issue #3. You read an int: `menuNum = keyboard.nextInt();` but the line is not over, so the next `nextLine` (`String stuName = keyboard.nextLine();`) takes the rest of the line. use `nextLine()` and parse the integers instead.

Comment: You may want to change that variable name. `continue` is a keyword.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just swtiched my do while loop to switch. Regarding the third issue, do you mean I have to use `nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()` in `menuNum = keyboard.nextInt();`  ? It is an integer I cant use it unless if I change `menuNum` to `String`

Comment: Read the nextLine into some string variable and use Integer.parseInt to parse the integer from it.

Comment: I have major today I'll continue solving this on weekend(wednesday) and I'll get back here. Thank you so much guys